# Is visiting Russia's MID required after passport renewal at embassy?

Tags: russia, passport-renewals, russian-citizens, embassies

does every russian citizen living in US who renews his/her international russian passport for 10 years (get a Biometric one) at the Russian Embassy in the US, get a paper saying to show up at the Russian MID  (Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Russian Federation) upon arrival to Russia? Has someone actually received it and has gone through the process?